# How to find my dropbox database ID

Tags: dropbox

I truly can't find it anywhere. Perhaps because when I first installed it, I deleted the public folder, I'm not sure.

I'm referring to this article: http://recovermydrive.com/use-dropbox-to-make-files-public-in-two-clicks/

Where you need your database ID. I can't find it. Is there any way to recover it? I've tried creating a map name 'Public', but that didn't work.

Comment: So, there is no folder "Public" when you log in to www.getdropbox.com?

Comment: No, there is no public folder. Also, I've tried several folders and files, but I can't set a single on to public.

Comment: See my edit about "Show deleted files". Or maybe create a new Public folder using the website? (On a Mac, without any third-party software, only files within the Public folder are public. In fact, all files added to that folder are public automatically. There's no such thing as "setting files to public".)

Comment: The Show deleted files shows no public folder... Tried to create one, didn't see an option to make it public.

Comment: I don't expect the Dropbox team has implemented some user interface to make the folder public. So, if the Public folder is not automatically recognised by its name and location (or, in other words: if files *within* a root folder that is named *Public* are not automatically publicly downloadable), then maybe the Dropbox forum (or helpdesk) is a better place to ask?

Comment: I shall go there than.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the article says: It is explained in the dialog window screenshot below.

> For instance, when a public link to your Dropbox is as follows:
>
> `http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1234567/desktop.ini`
>
> then your Dropbox database ID is 1234567

[image]

See also the Dropbox help: [How do I link to files in my Dropbox?](https://www.getdropbox.com/help/16)

As you deleted the Public folder: maybe that's easily recovered by clicking "Show deleted files" (will change to "Hide delete files" then, or will not be shown at all if there are no deleted files in the folder you're looking at) on your home at [www.getdropbox.com/home](https://www.getdropbox.com/)?

To get back a public folder, simply log into Dropbox and create a new folder at the root named "Public" and it will automatically assign itself as the public folder.

Comment: Are you actually claiming that I can come up with my own database ID? Have you even tried this?

Comment: No, that's not what the above is trying to say. It says you should make at least one file public (temporarily, if you want). And then, given the URL of that public file, you can find your ID. To make a file public: see the link to "How do I link to files in my Dropbox?". (But then: if you want to use that third-party tool to make it *easier* to make files public, you might already have some public files? Just pick one of those then, and see what its URL is.)

Comment: (And what about my comment about that Public folder on www.getdropbox.com?)